# Is there an HTML CSS testing bin similar to jsbin

Tags: html, css, testing

Is there a page similar to JSbin where I can test HTML and CSS + provide "fiddlable" examples to you?

Comment: You can do that very thing on JSbin

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-online-playgrounds-for-html-css-and-javascript-compared/

Comment: What about http://www.jsexample.com? very simple and bare bones..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes there is!

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Don't be put off by the 'js' in the name. It has fields for HTML, CSS and JS. You could leave the JS blank and just use the HTML and CSS.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9PLZ2/) is an example of `first-child` in CSS, to show how small your snippets can be.

Comment: How is jsFiddle anything different than jsBin? If anything it's worse cause you can't hide the views you don't need. I abandoned it for jsBin a long time ago. Though I understand that some people just like permanent 4 pain split view with a sticky side bar...

Answer (score 7):

**[Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/)**

This one is the new one on the block and it is **fantastic**! Integrates nicely with git as well :)

Comment: Only recently found this myself. It does look pretty good.

Comment: What's fantastic about it?

Answer (score 7):

### [CodePen.io](http://www.codepen.io)

I really like CodePen quite a bit. I pay for the pro version so I get a lot of realtime collaboration abilities as well as presentation modes. I use "professor mode" a lot because I mentor a few people and hold small online classes.

Answer (score 5):

## [jsDo.it](http://jsdo.it/)

Don't be put off by the 'js' in the name. It has fields for HTML, CSS and JS. You could leave the JS blank and just use the HTML and CSS.

[Here](http://jsdo.it/kzh/dlmQ/read) is an example of first-child in CSS, to show how small your snippets can be.

Excuse the blatant copy and paste, the same description works for this site, too. I, however prefer jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

## [CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/)

This one is nice if you don't need any JS.

Answer (score 4):

## [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com)

You can try [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com) . It even supports context-sensitive auto-completion for HTML5 & CSS3, which is really helpful for most web designers.